# How would I change the border color of a button?

Tags: c#, winforms

This is my code:

```
buttonName = "btn" + y.ToString() + x.ToString();
Control btn = this.Controls.Find(buttonName, true)[0] as Control;
btn.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Blue;
```

However, I see no border color changing properties, or the like.

I used this code because I have a lot of buttons on my form, and any of those buttons' properties can change, so rather than call them out individually, I just made up that code which could handle them.

Is there a code similar to the one above, that would allow me to change the border color of the button?

Comment: You don't see a border color changing, but in your code you set the BackColor of the Control...

Comment: Eh, the back ground color changes fine. But as for the Border color, I can't see any properties I could modify. Not from that code, anyway.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

I am not sure what sort of application you are working on, however in winforms there is no border property for a button directly on it, even in the designer.  You can use a flat style button. And your type will have to be button.

you can do it like:

```
buttonName = "btn" + y.ToString() + x.ToString();
Button btn = this.Controls.Find(buttonName, true)[0] as Button;
btn.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Blue;
btn.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat
btn.FlatAppearance.BorderColor = Color.Red;
btn.FlatAppearance.BorderSize = 1;
```

Unfortunately, this will only work on button with a FlatStyle.

Comment: Well, that was quick. Thanks! That bit of code works, if I make the following changes:
Button btn = this.Controls.Find(buttonName, true)[0] as Button;

Comment: yeah sorry missed that second entry when I copied your code. Edited answer

Comment: can also use Flat Appearance in the properties window

Answer (score 7):

you can use the flatAppearance.BorderColor

```
    btn.FlatAppearance.BorderColor = System.Drawing.Color.Blue;
```

Answer (score 5):

I know that this question is asked for a long time ago ( at 2011 ), but I think my comment will useful for someone : without using FlatStyle, you can use ControlPaint.DrawBorder in Paint event of the button you want to change the border color

```
    private void btnName_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        Button btn = (Button)sender;

        ControlPaint.DrawBorder(e.Graphics, btn.ClientRectangle,
                                Color.LightGreen, 1, ButtonBorderStyle.Solid,
                                Color.LightGreen, 1, ButtonBorderStyle.Solid,
                                Color.LightGreen, 1, ButtonBorderStyle.Solid,
                                Color.LightGreen, 1, ButtonBorderStyle.Solid
                                );
    }
```

According to Microsoft ([link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.controlpaint.drawborder?view=netframework-4.7.2))

> Applies to
>
> .NET Framework
>
> 4.7.2, 4.7.1, 4.7, 4.6.2, 4.6.1, 4.6, 4.5.2, 4.5.1, 4.5, 4.0, 3.5, 3.0, 2.0, 1.1

Answer (score 3):

Depending on your framework there is a new  property called BorderColor

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.flatbuttonappearance.bordercolor.aspx,

Have you checked that?

Also here is an example of something similar

[Change border color of Windows Forms Control on focus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4047651/change-border-color-of-windows-forms-control-on-focus)

Answer (score 1):

You need to cast your Control as Button (or whatever type it is).  Control is a base class, and will not contain properties to modify border colors.  Is this a windows app?

Comment: Yes, this is a windows app. How do I cast my control as a Button?

Comment: Button button = control as Button;
or
Button button = (Button)control;